# Boas práticas usando CSS

Tags: html, css

Quais são as boas práticas em CSS para manter o `código limpo`, `compacto` e `manutenível`?

- Deve-se utilizar uma forma mais simples e menos rígida de seletores?
  (Cenário: há uma div com uma imagem dentro)

Código de exemplo:

```
.caixa img{}
ou
div.caixa > img
```

- Deve-se utilizar seletores para agrupar características (ex: um
  seletor para deixar a cor do fundo verde e letras brancas) ou
  especificos para cada elemento comum (botão com a cor do fundo verde,
  letras brancas, borda preta e negrito)?
- Como deve ficar organizado no arquivo `.css` os seletores (ex: O
  Desenvolvedor vai adicionando novos seletores no final do arquivo)?
  Deve-se agrupar por arquivo `.html`, por elemento `tag HTML`, como
  seria organizado os seletores de classes que são genericas (ex: um 
  seletor para deixar a cor do fundo verde e letras brancas).
- Costumo colocar `id` em areas estuturais do `HTML` (corpo,
  menu-esquerdo, menu-direito), e criar um seletor desta forma:
  isso é má pratica? Aliviar o HTML em detrimento do CSS? seria melhor criar uma classe que conteria toda a aparencia dos elementos (o que deixaria o HTML cheio de classes)

Código exemplo:

```
#corpo, #menu-esquerdo, #menu-direito{}
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54267/discussion-on-question-by-ricardo-boas-praticas-usando-css)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Eu, pessoalmente recomendaria isso:

- Procure sempre a simplicidade no código. Evite seletores onde não for
  necessário. Se você cria um seletor `id` para a tag `body`, por
  exemplo, você pode esquecer que essa `id` se dirige a ela, portanto,
  sendo mais intuitivo selecionar pela própria tag. Mas no caso de
  elementos `div`, onde geralmente existe mais do que 1 elemento desse
  tipo na página, é interessante identificá-los com `id`.
- É preferível criar um seletor para cada elemento, a não ser quando há muito elementos com a mesma característica, daí é melhor usar `class`.
- É interessante usar a herança CSS a seu favor.
- Eu colocaria os estilos no CSS na mesma ordem em que os elementos aparecem no código HTML.
- No caso do seu exemplo, `div.caixa > img` parece ser melhor pois é mais específico. Isso evitaria que o CSS "vaze" para elementos onde não deve ser aplicado.
- Agrupar seletores é interessante quando tem funções parecidas, mas não estão em quantidade que seja interessante ou não faz sentido a criação de uma `class` e essa só dificultaria a leitura do código.
- É interessante usar o seletor `*`, que seleciona todos os elementos da página, para dar um reset geral no CSS e evitar problemas em decorrência da folha de estilos nativa do navegador.
- Também me parece uma boa prática criar uma `div` dentro do `body` e colocar todo o conteúdo nela se você usa plugins de terceiros na sua página, pois esses geralmente imprimem o código dentro da tag `body` e, dessa forma, você poderia ter maior controle e reduzir a chance de conflitos.

Comment: Concordo com o Carlos e ainda recomendo a utilização de algum pré-processador CSS como por exemplo o SASS ou Stylus

Comment: Gostaria apenas de contribuir: Eu gosto muito que minhas classes indiquem que determinada coisa **é um**. O Bootstrap por exemplo usa este conceito, ex: **form-control**, **input-lg**, etc... Acho que isso é uma abordagem interessante.

Comment: Boa resposta, só discordo do CSSReset, veja: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8357635/1518921

Answer (score 18):

CSS é um acrônimo para **C**ascading **S**tyle **S**heets. O **C**ascading (cascateamento, cascata, você escolhe...) refere-se justamente a capacidade de criar seletores do tipo

```
.container .wrapper ul.lista > li:first-child span
```

que pode ser lido como "O span dentro do primeiro elemento filho direto de uma lista de classe `.lista` dentro de um `.wrapper` dentro de um `.container`. Esse tipo de especificidade é um dos pormenores mais interessantes do CSS, e pode, ao mesmo tempo, ser extremamente poderoso e perigoso. O grande segredo, que talvez responda a sua pergunta, é saber quando usar um seletor *rigido*, conforme você colocou (o caso do meu exemplo), e quando ser mais flexível e simplesmente criar uma classe `.meu_elemento`, atribuí-la ao `<span>` e economizar um monte de linhas. O que nos leva às boas práticas (aquilo que eu considero como, pelo menos). Mas primeiro, vale a pena responder uma pergunta:

**O código é meu?**

Nada melhor do que [este gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foCaz.jpg) para explicar o meu ponto. Certa vez, tive que dar manutenção em um código que foi mantido por outro desenvolvedor durante cerca de 2 anos, e depois abandonado. Nesse tipo de situação, sempre procurei ser bem especifico (i.e., criar seletores que vão acertar a menor quantidade possível de elementos). Dessa maneira, é mais difícil de eu mudar algo sem querer.

Uma vez dito isso, e partindo do pressuposto que você quer *sempre* criar um CSS legível e de fácil manuntenção, vamos para as boas práticas:

1. **CSS Reset**

   Independente do tamanho do seu projeto, se é o site de uma padaria ou o maior e-commerce da galáxia, use um [reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html). Resets essencialmente corrigem inconsistências entre browsers, como margens, alturas e etc. Alguns frameworks já vem com resets embutidos, o que nos leva ao segundo ponto.
2. **Frameworks**

   Tem gente que torce o nariz quando escuta a palavra *framework*. Eu já acredito que, se alguém (ou uma equipe de alguéns) devotou tempo para desenvolver algo, cujo foco é a escalabilidade, porquê reinventar a roda? [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) e [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) talvez sejam uns dos mais famosos. Eu, particularmente, estou usando (e aprovando) o [Suzy](http://susy.oddbird.net/), que é um framework em SASS um pouco menos rigido. Ah...
3. **Pré-processadores**

   Variáveis no CSS? Loops? Condicionais? Nesting? Pré-processadores lhe permitem tudo isso e mais um monte de outras vantagens. [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) e [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) são os mais famosos, acredito. Pré-processadores, além de tornar o seu código MUITO mais legível, lhe permitem um grau maior de propagação. Caso você opte por seletores mais específicos, o nesting dos processadores, junto com seus `mixins` e `extends`, tornam as coisas bem mais fáceis. Já que estamos falando de especificidade...
4. **IDs ou Classes?**

   Já se sabe do berço que `IDs` definem elementos únicos na sua página, enquanto classes são usadas para elementos que se repetem. Uma coisa que você *NUNCA* deve fazer é ter `<div id="container">` duas vezes na sua página. Apesar disso funcionar, e de você não ter variações gritantes na performance, isto não é uma boa prática.

   O ideal é sempre que você sentir que algo está se repetindo com frequência no seu CSS, é que aquilo torne-se uma classe, sempre que possível. Se, por razões, vários elementos conterem as propriedades `float: left` e `line-height: 1.5`, experimente criar uma classe contendo as duas propriedades e distribuí-la, conforme a sua lógica, pelo seu mark-up. Deixe os `IDs` para elementos ou blocos de elementos específicos, que merecem uma atenção especial.
5. **HTML e CSS inline**

   Se você está indo e vindo com frequência para o seu HTML, fazendo ajustes para que suas definições de estilo funcionem, você está fazendo isso errado. Procure, quando você pode, definir o seu HTML da maneira mais simples possível, agrupando elementos que se repetem e evitando ao máximo CSS inline.
6. **Especificidade VS Generalização**

   Talvez aqui que esteja o ponto principal da pergunta. Em um código

   ```
   <div class="images">
       <img src="/img/1.jpg" alt="">
       <img src="/img/2.jpg" alt="">
       <img src="/img/3.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
   ```

   Devo usar, como seletor, `.images img`, `div.images img`, `div.images > img`, ou talvez uma classe para as imagens?

   Eu, particularmente, faço uma análise da hierarquia do meu código. Se eu sou genérico demais, e o meu projeto tende a aumentar, pode ser que o meu seletor acerte algo que eu não planejei. Por outro lado, se eu sou extremamente específico, talvez o meu código se torne muito repetitivo, pois estaria adicionando as mesmas prioridades a mais de uma classe ou elemento, o que causa um bloat extremo.

Basicamente, tudo depende de como você arquiteta o seu projeto, e de como ele cresce (lembre-se, nem sempre você tem controle sobre todo o HTML). Generalização pode ser bom, mas como tende a atingir mais elementos, você pode chegar ao ponto de ter uma `<div>` que é apontada por 5, 6, 7 regras diferentes. Quanto mais regras em um elemento, mais difícil é de mantê-lo e alterá-lo. Especificidade impede que esse tipo de coisa aconteça, mas pode tornar o seu código repetitivo e nada escalável. Eu acredito que frameworks ajudam a contornar esse problema, mas nada que a própria experiência não te diga como fazer. O segredo é achar o ponto de equilibrio entre as duas coisas, sem afetar a performance, e sem fazer com que você arranque os cabelos.

**EDIT**:

Ainda em tempo: Encontrei um artigo que, apesar de antigo, é bastante interessante, e trata das especificidades dos seletores. Ele pode ser lido [aqui](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/specificity_wars.php).

Answer (score 3):

Um dos *design patterns* mais utilizados atualmente no CSS é o chamado **BEM**.

BEM, acrônimo de "Block, Element, Modifier", nada mais é do que usar nomenclaturas padronizadas de forma a ajudar um desenvolvedor a identificar a função de uma classe CSS só de bater o olho no seu nome. Ela utiliza o padrão: `.bloco__elemento--modificador`.

Um bom exemplo de uso prático seria o código abaixo:

```
<div class="contador">
    <button class="contador__botao contador__botao--subtrair"> - </button>
    <input class="contador__campo" type="number">
    <button class="contador__botao contador__botao--somar"> + </button>
</div>
```

Onde as classes do exemplo acima representariam:

> - `.contador`: classe geral do bloco-pai do que será estilizado;
> - `.contador__input`: classe referente à todos os inputs pertencentes ao bloco-pai.
> - `.contador__botão`: classe referente à todos os botões pertencentes à este bloco-pai;
> - `.contador__botao--subtrair/somar`: modificador do botão (continua sendo um botão, mas possuindo um subtipo, neste caso, "somar" ou "subtrair".

Onde ao bater o olho, qualquer conhecedor to padrão conseguiria identificar exatamente as funções de cada classe sem mesmo ver seu conteúdo.

**Entre as vantagens de se usar o BEM como padrão estão:**

- Padronização de nomenclatura;
- Fácil identificação das funções das classes antes mesmo de ver o código;
- Melhor manutenção e escalabilidade em projetos grandes (por causa da padronização);
- Prevenção de conflito entre propriedades e classes CSS.

**Entre as desvantagens, temos por principal:**

- Nomenclatura esteticamente "feia" (classes com nomes grandes);
- "Engessamento" de classes (ao invés de uma classe `.btn` para todos os buttons, teríamos `.escopoX__btn`, .`escopoY__btn`, etc.

BEM, assim como [outros padrões em ascendência](http://tableless.com.br/oocss-smacss-bem-dry-css-afinal-como-escrever-css/) no mercado tem seus pontos fortes e fracos, e assim como qualquer padrão no mundo da TI, deve ser avaliado e usado de acordo sua utilidade no projeto.