# É uma má prática criar um arquivo CSS para cada tela?

Tags: css

Eu acho mais prático e mais fácil de dar manutenção se eu criar um arquivo CSS por tela. Essa é uma má prática? O mesmo pode ser feito com arquivos JS?

Comment: Defina má prática.

Comment: Algo que vá contra as boas práticas do desenvolvimento web.

Comment: Isso não quer dizer nada.

Comment: As boas práticas definem padrões de organização de código e arquivos para facilitar a compreensão e manutenção dos mesmos. Uma má prática seria fazer algo fora desses padrões e que deixe a aplicação desorganizada internamente, fazendo assim que a vida de outras pessoas, que forem mexer no seu código, se torne mais dificil.

Comment: Principalmente baseada em opiniões, né?

Comment: Não há como não ser, @jbueno. Se não for, é uma ampla discussão sobre o assunto.

Comment: @HiagoMachado Mas ainda depende de um ponto de partida. Entenda que boa prática pra mim e pra minha equipe pode ser má prática pra você e pra sua equipe. Sem contar que depende do projeto, de especificações, de como você quer que tudo funcione. Já ouviu falar que não existe "receita de bolo" pra programar? Pois então, é (também) sobre isto que esta frase fala. Esta pergunta é inválida por este simples fato, boa prática depende de quem vê e como vê. Você muito vai ouvir falar em boas práticas e boa parte do pessoal que cita isso é porque quer inventar uma regrinha sem precisar de embasamento.

Comment: Não é baseada em opiniões se tiver um contexto, uma explicação plausível do que deseja, onde quer chegar. Precisaria ver onde viu isso, ou se tirou da cartola, se vê algum problema, indicar melhor o que está fazendo, talvez esteja mais pra ampla que opinião.

Comment: Se for analisar bem, "má prática" e "boa prática" não existem. É sinônimo de "não sei o que estou fazendo, então vou copiar o que dizem". Ou tem um motivo real, ou não tem. Se tem, não é boa prática, e sim conhecimento (e a razão pra fazer ou não vem desse conhecimento, e não da "prática"). Se não tem razão real, é chute, pois cada caso é um caso. Talvez se você puser um contexto mais específico na pergunta, seja possível uma resposta técnica adequada.

Comment: Veja aí talvez clareie algo ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336302/single-huge-css-file-vs-multiple-smaller-specific-css-files

Comment: Acho que isso não se enquadra em uma prática ruim ou boa, mas vai te dar um trabalho adicional. Pode dificultar a reutilização de classes também

Comment: Leia esse post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67499/folha-de-estilo-diferente-para-cada-p%C3%A1gina-ou-somente-uma

Comment: Como você faz  do lado servidor, mantendo um nível de organização de arquivos e conteúdo por arquivo, com CSS e JavaScript não é diferente. Você pode desenvolver o estilo visual do seu site e estruturar as regras CSS em diversos arquivos, cada um com referência à uma parte em particular. Ex: Para a estrutura, estrutura.css Para a navegação, navegacao.css Para os elementos de formulário, forms.css

Comment: É tudo uma questão de opinião. A minha opinião é que acha mais prático repetir código se você tem um arquivo CSS por página e houver qualquer coisa comum entre eles.

Comment: Geralmente crio um css que terá os estilos comum em todas as páginas (geralmente usado em templates), depois o css que cada página necessita. No final compilo todos estes css em um só minificando tudo inclusive.

Comment: É claramente uma má prática e vou dizer o porque.

1- Dificulta a manutenção do código. Imagina que ele estilize o elemento H1 da mesma maneira por todo o site. Quando resolver mudar o visual do H1 terá que mudar em todos os arquivos. Isso vai contra o conceito de reutilização de código.

2- Cada novo arquivo irá gerar uma requisição HTTP nova e quando menos requisição HTTP melhor. Uma vez baixado o arquivo css ele vai ficar no cache para as outras páginas. Será apenas uma requisição.

E gente lógico que más e boas práticas existem. Existem tonelada de livros e estudos sobre isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olha. Eu também sou da opinião de fazer o que você acha melhor para você, mas se você quer uma luz em o que é considerado "melhor", existem aqueles que vão falar do que é mais custo/benefício para a sua página.

Neste [link](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/inline-vs-separate-file), ele analisa quantidades de envio e recebimento de dados e conclui que o melhor é anexar arquivos externos apenas se tiverem mais de ½KB, fora isso é melhor que se junte tudo ou escreva inline.

Mas enfim, ele mesmo diz que o peso para a página não é lá tão significante assim. O melhor a se fazer **nesse sentido**, é o que for mais confortável para você. Como disseram, boas e más práticas são relativas.

Mas agora, na minha opinião, se você vai dividir suas folhas por telas, eu ainda acho que você deveria ter ao menos uma folha principal para classes básicas que você vai repetir em todas as suas telas.