# O que é CSS BEM?

Tags: css, bem

Eu vi que algumas pessoas estão adotando o padrão de colocar algumas classes em CSS separadas por um duplo underline.

Exemplo:

```
.form__field{
   /** Css aqui **/
}
```

Eu nunca tinha nada a respeito, e me deparei com o termo *CSS BEM* ou *BEM*.

Gostaria de saber do que se trata.

- É um padrão novo?
- Qual é o objetivo do mesmo?
- Quais problemas ele resolve?

Comment: CSS é do MAL, sempre :D

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Boas práticas usando CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65783/boas-pr%C3%A1ticas-usando-css/69348#69348). Uma das respostas é sobre o BEM

Comment: É mais uma dessas coisas que criaram para resolver o problema de quem mistura uma monte de tranqueira, que poderia ser feito de forma simples, mas que as pessoas com pouco conhecimento acham que já tem o suficiente de entendimento sobre CSS (mas nem sabem o que são rules) e nem imaginam o quão as coisas poderiam ser simplificadas e obter o mesmo resultado, ai tem que inventar coisas para resolver dificuldades criadas pelas proprias pessoas por quererem usar uma série de cacarecos e tentar (apenas tentar mesmo) evitar se embananarem.

Comment: Votei +1 (e talvez vote para manter aberta, vou esperar a comunidade) porque a pergunta 'me parece' que poderia ter um foco só sobre o assunto... e **não vejo nem de longe** o `BEM` como algo útil, na verdade pessoalmente acho que o não precisar de `BEM` e simplificar seria uma real *"boa pratica"*, uma pergunta focada no uso do `BEM`, mas sem falar que ele é maravilhoso, só falar quando é útil, tipo esses projetos avacalhados (não levem a mal). Então acho que este lugar/pergunta é o local para falar do assunto, talvez eu até me atreva a responder.

Comment: Um adendo ao meu outro comentário, já me deparei com trabalho dos outros de uma página (uma "landingpage" promocional) bem simples, com BEM, com FLEX, com GRID, que no final ficou um pouco maior que o esperado. Pois é, as supostas *"boas praticas"* geradas por pessoas que esqueceram de aprender o básico, mas conseguem usar uma coisa nova para fazer umas 10 coisas diferentes, que geralmente nem seriam necessárias ou adequadas, devem seguir a filosofia: *"faça o BEM sem olhar a quem"* :p

Answer (score 14, accepted):

BEM não é um padrão novo, é uma convenção já com alguns anos. O objectivo é que os nomes das classes CSS sejam de certa forma relaccionáveis com o HTML e aumentar a legibilidade do CSS produzido.
BEM significa Block Element Modifier, em Português - bloco, elemento, modificador.

O bloco é o "contentor" principal, o elemento usa dois underscores e o modificador usa dois hifens.
Por exemplo:

```html
<a class="btn btn--red" href="#">
    <span class="btn__icon"></span>
    <span class="btn__text">Subscribe</span>
</a>
```

neste exemplo podemos ver o "bloco" `btn` e o seu "modificador" `btn--red`. Dentro do "bloco" podemos também ver os seus elementos filhos: `btn__icon` e `btn__text`.

No ficheiro CSS seria claro que as classes pertencem a um determinado elemento:

```
.btn {
   color:blue;
}
.btn--red {
   color: red;
}
.btn__icon {
 }
.btn__text {
 }
```

Comment: Só comentando que vc tb pode ter o modificador direto no "element", por ex: `btn__text--red { }`, isso tb estaria de acordo com a convenção BEM.

Answer (score 4):

É uma arquitetura CSS desenvolvida por uma russa que trabalha ou trabalhava no buscador Yandex. O site oficial é esse https://en.bem.info/

Segundo essa arquiteta, você pode organizar o seu css em blocos, elementos de bloco e modificadores dos blocos ou dos elementos de bloco. Se você já brincou no lego, é como montar um boneco. O boneco é um bloco, as suas pernas, braços e cabeça são os seus elementos; Você pode ter uma das perna de madeira, uma mão com um cacho, um chapeu de pirata e o seu boneco pode ser azul. (eu nunca brinquei com lego, então... relevem a minha analogia. kkk).

Por exemplo:

```
<ul class="list list--row">
    <li class="list__item">
        <a href="#"
           class="list__link list__link--current">...</a>

    </li>
    <li class="list__item">
        <a href="#"
           class="list__link">...</a>

    </li>
    <li class="list__item">
        <a href="#"
           class="list__link list__link--disabled">...</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

```
<style>

.list,
.list__item,
.list__link {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list,
.list__item {
    list-style: none;
}

.list--row {
    display: flex;
}

.list__item,
.list__link {
    display: inline-block;
}

.list__item {
    margin: 0 5px;
}


.list__link {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: #1e90ff;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}

.list__link--current {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1e90ff;
}

.list__link--disabled {
    color: #ccc;
    cursor: text;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

BEM é a sigla pra *Block Element Modifier* (Bloco Elemento Modificador), é uma metodologia baseada nessas três entidades que deifne regras de nomenclatura, estrutura dos arquivos e escrita do código

[Bloco](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/#block): Um componente de página funcionalmente independente que pode ser reutilizado

[Elemento](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/#element): Uma parte composta de um bloco que não pode ser usada separadamente dele

[Modificador](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/#modifier): Define a parência, estado ou comportamento de um bloco ou elemento

[Nomenclatura](https://en.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/#naming-rules):

- Os nomes são escritos em letras latinas minúsculas.
- As palavras são separadas por um hífen (`-`).
- O nome do bloco define o namespace para seus elementos e modificadores.
- O nome do elemento é separado do nome do bloco por um sublinhado duplo (`__`).
- O nome do modificador é separado do nome do bloco ou elemento por um único sublinhado (`_`).
- O valor do modificador é separado do nome do modificador por um único sublinhado (`_`).
- Para modificadores booleanos, o valor não é incluído no nome.

Há também [esquemas de nomenclatura alternativos](https://en.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/#alternative-naming-schemes):

- Estilo de dois traços: `block-name__elem-name--mod-name--mod-val`
- Estilo CamelCase: `blockName-elemName_modName_modVal`
- Estilo React: `BlockName-ElemName_modName_modVal`
- Estilo sem namespace: `_available`

Além desses, é permitido criar uma nomenclatura própria de acordo com as necessidades

Ele define uma [estrutura de arquivos](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/#file-structure) baseada na nomenclatura das classes, separando em diferentes arquivos as diferentes tecnologias

Podendo ter uma [estrutura aninhada](https://en.bem.info/methodology/filestructure/#nested):

```
project
    common.blocks                            # Nível de redefinição com blocos
        input                                # Diretório pro bloco input
            _type                            # Diretório pro modificador input_type
                input_type_search.css        # Implementação CSS do modificador input_type
            __clear                          # Diretório pro elemento input__clear
                _visible                     # Diretório pro modificador input__clear_visible
                    input__clear_visible.css # Implementação CSS do modificador input__clear_visible
                input__clear.css             # Implementação CSS do elemento input__clear
                input__clear.js              # Implementação JavaScript do elemento input__clear 
        input.css                            # Implementação CSS do bloco input
        input.js                             # Implementação JavaScript do bloco input
```

[Estrutura plana](https://en.bem.info/methodology/filestructure/#flat):

```
project
    common.blocks
        input_type_search.css     # Implementação CSS do modificador input_type_search
        input_type_search.js      # Implementação JavaScript do modificador input_type_search
        input__clear.js           # Elemento opcional do bloco input
        input.css
        input.js
        popup.css
        popup.js
        popup.png
```

Ou [flex](https://en.bem.info/methodology/filestructure/#flex), que é uma mistura de ambos

```
project
    common.blocks                            # Nível de redefinição com blocos
        input                                # Diretório pro bloco input
            _type                            # Diretório pro modificador input_type
                input_type_search.css        # Implementação CSS do modificador input_type
            __clear                          # Diretório pro elemento input__clear
                _visible                     # Diretório pro modificador input__clear_visible
                    input__clear_visible.css # Implementação CSS do modificador input__clear_visible
                input__clear.css             # Implementação CSS do elemento input__clear
                input__clear.js              # Implementação JavaScript do elemento input__clear 
        input.css                            # Implementação CSS do bloco input
        input.js                             # Implementação JavaScript do bloco input
        popup                                # Diretório pro bloco popup
            popup.css
            popup.js
            popup.png
```

Como pode perceber, abaixo do diretório raiz do projeto (`project`), há outro (`common.blocks`), isso faz parte dos [níveis de redefinição](https://en.bem.info/methodology/redefinition-levels/), a ideia é poder dividir o código em "subprojetos", por exemplo, `common.blocks` com o *core* e `mobile.blocks` e `desktop.blocks` com as especifidades das interfaces desktop e mobile, respectivamente. Os arquivos específicos podem sobrescrever totalmente ou parcialmente as classes do *core*, ou até não haver especificidades de determinadas entidades

É adotado também alguns *design patterns* conhecidos ...

- [Princípio de responsabilidade única](https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#single-responsibility-principle): Uma classe deve ter uma e somente uma responsabilidade, ou seja, uma classe modificadora `.button_red` deve apenas alterar o estilo do botão pra vermelho, não deve alterar seu posicionamento, estado ou outra característica que não esteja intimamente relacionada ao seu proposito principal (estilo vermelho)
- [Princípio aberto-fechado](https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#openclosed-principle): Alterações no CSS devem ser feitas por "extensão", criando um novo modificador e não alterando estilos atuais diretamente ou alterando sob determinado contexto (ser filho de um outro elemento)
- [DRY](https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#dry) ("*don't repeat yourself*"): Está diretamente relacionado aos princípios anteriores, as classes CSS devem ser genéricas, de forma que possam ter características específicas através dos modificadores, ou seja, não deve haver duas classes que fazem quase a mesma coisa, em vez disso, cria uma classe com o geral e dois modificadores com as especificadades
- [Composição em vez de herança](https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#composition-instead-of-inheritance): Novas implementações CSS são formadas combinando as existentes, isso mantém o código desacoplado e flexível, por exemplo, se você já possui os blocos `.button`, `.menu` e `.popup`, para a criação de um *drop-down list*, não é necessário um novo bloco, basta usar os existentes e definir corretamente o seus comportamentos

[Não é recomendada a utilização de wrappers para posicionamento de blocos](https://en.bem.info/methodology/html/#using-html-wrappers), em vez disso, deve ser utilizado mixes:

- Para posicionar dois blocos irmãos (`header` e `content`), relativos um ao outro, pode-se criar um bloco pai (`.card`) e utilizar dois blocos filhos (`.card__header` e `.card__content`) que terão os estilos de posicionamento, além dos blocos originais que serão mixados com os blocos filhos (`.card__header.header` e `.card__content.content`)

```html
<section class="card">
    <!-- Header and navigation -->
    <header class="header card__header">...</header>
    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="content card__content">...</div>
</section>
```

- Se os elementos a serem posicionados já forem pais e filhos, pode-se usar uma entidade elemento para lidar com o posicionamento, substituindo um wrapper abstrato

```html
<button class="button">
    <span class="button__start">
        <span class="icon"></span>
    </span>

    ...
</button>
```

A criação do HTML pode ser feita [manualmente](https://en.bem.info/methodology/html/#creating-html-manually), ou seja, escrever todo o código na mão, o que, a longo prazo, é ruim do ponto de vista da manutenção, já que uma alteração na estrutura das entidades requer alterar o HTML em múltiplos pontos

Mas é possível fazer isso [automaticamente](https://en.bem.info/methodology/html/#automatic-html-generation), através de modelos, ao alterá-lo, os elementos HTML existentes serão atualizados também, podendo ser trocado por outro ou estendido por novos. Os modelos são escritos de forma declarativa, permitindo que seja aplicado os principais princípios da metodologia:

- [Utilização dos mesmos termos](https://en.bem.info/methodology/html/#unified-subject-domain): Os modelos são definidos nos termos bloco, elemento e modificador, para isso, existe uma abstração acima da árvore DOM, a [árvore BEM](https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/#bem-tree), que é um "DOM simplificado", apenas com as entidades, por exemplo, o seguinte código HTML:

```html
<header class="header">
    <img class="logo">
    <form class="search-form">
        <input class="input">
        <button class="button"></button>
    </form>
    <ul class="lang-switcher">
        <li class="lang-switcher__item">
            <a class="lang-switcher__link" href="url">en</a>
        </li>
        <li class="lang-switcher__item">
            <a class="lang-switcher__link" href="url">ru</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Teria a correspondente árvore BEM:

```html
header
    logo
    search-form
        input
        button
    lang-switcher
        lang-switcher__item
            lang-switcher__link
        lang-switcher__item
            lang-switcher__link
```

- [Divisão do código](https://en.bem.info/methodology/html/#dividing-the-code-into-parts): O código do modelo é armazenado em arquivos de bloco separados de acordo com as regras de organização da estrutura de arquivos. É possível criar modelos para um bloco inteiro ou, separadamente, para elementos ou modificadores
- [Utilização de níveis de redefinição](https://en.bem.info/methodology/html/#redefining-a-template): É a mesma ideia já descrita antes, aplicado também aos templates, podendo adicionar e remover entidades a estrutura ou renderizar as mesmas entidades de forma diferente (por exemplo, alterando a tag HTML utilizada)

A metodologia se aplica também ao JavaScript, mantendo o foco nas entidades e organizando o código de acordo com a estrutura de arquivos já explicada, incluindo os níveis de redefinição, onde é possível adicionar, sobrescrever ou herdar as entidades. Para que tudo funcione corretamente e as alterações no DOM não afetem o funcionamento dos blocos, é importante a implementação através da biblioteca [`i-bem.js`](https://en.bem.info/technology/i-bem/current/i-bem-js-mods/) (há também o [BEM React](https://en.bem.info/technologies/bem-react/), um conjunto de ferramentas para implementar a metodologia no React)

Há algumas regras de escrita de código também...

- [Estilo declarativo](https://en.bem.info/methodology/js/#declarative-style):

  - O comportamento de cada bloco é descrito separadamente
  - Os estados do bloco são definidos declarativamente e, ao mudar, é automaticamente chamado o código que definido para este estado
  - A lógica do bloco é descrita como um conjunto de ações e condições para a execução dessas ações, isso torna possível separar a funcionalidade do bloco em partes individuais e usar os níveis de redefinição
- [Encapsulamento](https://en.bem.info/methodology/js/#encapsulation): A implementação de um bloco é separada de outros blocos e cada bloco fornece uma API para interagir com outros blocos. A declaração de bloco permite ocultar sua implementação interna e, como os elementos são sempre uma implementação interna de um bloco, eles podem ser acessados apenas por meio da API do bloco
- [Herança](https://en.bem.info/methodology/js/#inheritance): A descrição declarativa do comportamento do bloco torna possível usar os métodos de um bloco base dentro de um bloco derivado e herdá-los, então, o novo bloco pode obter todas as propriedades e métodos do bloco base. Você também pode criar cadeias de herança, o que significa que um bloco herda de outro que, por sua vez, herda de um terceiro bloco e assim por diante
- [Interação entre blocos](https://en.bem.info/methodology/js/#interaction-between-blocks): A metodologia BEM preza por trabalhar com blocos independentes, mas, na prática, isso é inatingível. A comunicação entre blocos pode ser através de:

  - Inscrições para eventos de outras instâncias de blocos
  - Assinaturas para mudanças nos modificadores
  - Chamadas diretas aos métodos de outras instâncias ou aos métodos estáticos de outros blocos
  - Quaisquer padrões de interação. Por exemplo, *Event Channel*: toda a comunicação ocorre por meio de mensagens que os componentes publicam e ouvem usando um intermediário
- [Interação de um bloco com seus elementos](https://en.bem.info/methodology/js/#interaction-of-a-block-with-its-elements): Um bloco normalmente possui auxiliares adicionais para trabalhar com seus elementos, que são a implementação interna de um bloco. Não é possível acessar um elemento de outro bloco diretamente, só pode ser acessado por meio da API do bloco ao qual esse elemento pertence

Tentei simplificar e resumir as partes, há mais pra se aprofundar e também algumas coisas que não coloquei aqui como [build](https://en.bem.info/methodology/build/) e [problemas comuns](https://en.bem.info/methodology/solved-problems/), assim como as diversas ferramentas ([tecnologias](https://en.bem.info/technologies/), [toolbox](https://en.bem.info/toolbox/) e [bibliotecas](https://en.bem.info/libraries/))

Agora respondendo as perguntas no corpo...

- É um padrão novo?

Não, de acordo com sua [história](https://en.bem.info/methodology/history/), existe desde 2005, mas de seus primórdios até hoje mudou tudo

- Qual é o objetivo do mesmo?

No início, provavelmente, apenas padronizar como o código CSS é escrito, hoje, é uma metodologia que tem diversos padrões e regras pra criar um código organizado, reaproveitável e de fácil manutenção

- Quais problemas ele resolve?

Ele resolve certos problemas ao se trabalhar em equipe, como um componente sobrescrever outro e a desorganização tanto do código como da estrutura. Também, como disse, a metodologia foca no desenvolvimento de componentes reaproveitáveis e de fácil manutenção.

Em contrapartida, traz muita complexidade e algumas limitações, como utilizar classes (`.checked`) modificadoras em vez de pseudo-classes (`:checked`), o que seria mais prático, e não reaproveitamento de modificadores (por exemplo, `.bolder` pra negrito) entre elementos e blocos, mas há alternativas

A metodologia **NÃO** padroniza a nomenclatura das classes, como descrito mais acima, ela possui 5 padrões próprios e ainda permite que os desenvolvedores criem seus próprios padrões. Então, de qualquer forma, os desenvolvedores terão que se organizar pra decidir como as classes devem ser nomeadas

Todos os links da resposta foram retirados da [documentação](https://bem.info/)

Comment: Para manter a resposta objetiva, vou deixar nos comentários minha opinião... A metodologia traz alguns padrões/regras interesantes, porém a adoção total dificilmente será benéfico, é muito complexa, há uma separação em muitos arquivos desnecessariamente, o código fica muito poluído com muitas classes e nomes grandes. Pré-processadores CSS (SASS, Stylus, etc) oferecem ferramentas úteis que podem ser utilizados no lugar de alguns padrões para manter o código mais simples e limpo