# O que é o padrão utility-first no CSS?

Tags: html, css

No CSS, existem padrões como o [BEM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/422460/69296) que visam à organização da nomenclatura das classes do CSS.

Recentemente, com a ascensão de bibliotecas como o [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/), percebi a existência de um novo<sup>*</sup> modelo de CSS (agora ainda mais atrelado ao HTML) chamado *utility-first*.

Para quem não tem muito contato com esse padrão de CSS, o código HTML (que agora é, também, responsável pela estilização) parece ficar mais poluído.

- Quais são as vantagens do modelo *utility-first*?
- E as desvantagens?
- <sup>*</sup>É um padrão novo?
- Qual o objetivo do mesmo e quais problemas ele resolve?

Comment: Eu vou comentar com um link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/432733/metodologia-de-escrita-css-usando-no-nome-da-classe-tailwind-css, eu entendo perfeitamente que não responde a subpergunta `Quais são as vantagens do modelo utility-first?`, mas responde ao resto. Em resumo, se alguém pegar "X" e resolver começar a usar para um caso especifico eles podem até inventar uma tal metodologia, mas isso nem quer dizer que é bom, só quer dizer que as pessoas gostaram e para elas foi pratico e argumentos a favor serão puro "marketing", **as pessoas confundem "gostar" de algo com "ser melhor"**.

Comment: Eu penso em uma abordagem um pouco diferente hj em dia sobre isso, quando der um tempinho vou postar em uma resposta com alguns detalhes que ainda não vi em outros lugares

Answer (score 3):

**Primeiro. O que é o padrão CSS utility-first ?**

É uma abordagem de CSS escrita fazendo uso das chamadas classes utilitárias ou funcionais**. As mesmas representam atributos do CSS,diversos como *width*, *font-size*, etc... Exixtem diferentes nomes para a abordagem oou padrão chamado de *utility-first*, entre os nomes sinônimos temos: Immutable CSS, Functional CSS (CSS Funcional) e Atomic CSS.

As imagens abaixo retirados da fonte mencionada abaixo, podem nos demonstrar qual é a diferença de aplicação:

**Abordagem convencional de escrita do CSS**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS Convencional</title>
    <style>
        circle.round {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: black;
            border-radius: 100%;
        }
                
    </style>
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="circle-round"></div>    
    
</body>
</html>
```

**Abordagem funcional de escrita do CSS**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS funcional (utility-first)</title>
    <style>
            
        .w-100 {
            width: 100px;
        }
        
        .h-100 {
            height: 100px;
        }
        
        .bg-black {
            background-color: black;
        }
        
        .round-full {
            border-radius: 100%;
        }
                
    </style>
    
</head>
<body>

    <div class=" .w-100 .h-100 .bg-black .round-full"></div>    
    
</body>
</html>
```

**Reparou na diferença entre as duas?**
Dividimos a classe *circle-round* em diversas classes com as funcionalidades em cada uma separada.

**Utility First é o mesmo que Functional CSS**. É uma abordagem que procura trazer conceitos do paradigma (padrão de desenvolvimento) para as folhas de estilo CSS.

Conceitos:

**Composição ao invés de herança**

É escrito usando apenas uma propriedade de cada vez, não necessitando reescrever uma propriedade. O *utility-first* te força a compor os estilos dos elementos na página.

**Imutabilidade**

Pense que  você possui um site com inúmeros inputs espalhados por ele, e você esteja usando uma arquitetura de classes.

Agora imagine que você quer que apenas alterar a propriedade *button*.

O que você precisará fazer? Se alterar a classe .*button*, que é usada por todos, *desconfigurar* o que você não quer, certo ?
Com *Functional CSS*, você apenas atrela a aquele botão especifico, a propriedade ou conjunto de propriedades de que precisa.

Desta forma *<Button class=”classe1 class2 classe3 classe4”>*, já escritas anteriormente no código.

*Utility First* é uma escrita de classes *que alterem apenas uma propriedade do CSS de cada vez*, de maneira que no seu HTML você só precise compor seus elementos usando essas classes.

**Qual o objetivo do mesmo e quais problemas ele resolve (vantagens) ?**

Não precisa se preocupar com nomes para as classes, pois as mesmas terão nomes simples como por exemplo:  .w-100 .h-100 .bg-black .round-full, cada nome especificando o que faz a classe.

**Apenas precisamos usar as classes e ir montando nossa aplicação.**

***A escalabilidade de CSS pode não ser um problema***

Você tem um controle maior sobre a estilização do elemento css que deseja, de forma mais rápida, do que na abordagem convencional.

***Mudanças mais fáceis de realizar***

Para alterar um botão por exemplo, apenas usando a classe com a propriedade que queremos definir, sem precisar ter que pensar em algum nome mirabolante para a mesma.

**Desvantagens?**

O maior desafio será a **componentização**.  Pode-se tornar cansativo, imagine quantos locais precisarão ser alterados para simplesmente mudar a borda de 4px para 8px!. Esse problema pode ser solucionado usando componentização, criando um componentes Button por exemplo, e com todos as classes padrão definidas. Para iniciantes utilizar a  componentização pode não ser algo tão simples. Outro desafio é a questão da responsividade que pode ser resolvida
utilizando os modificadores do *[Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/)*.

**É um padrão novo?**

R: Creio que não é um padrão novo, porém pouco conhecido pelo nome, talvez muitos já utilizem com outro nome. Os artigos mais antigos que encontrei datam o ano de 2018.

**Créditos e fonte:** https://blog.codecasts.com.br/conhecendo-css-utility-first-com-tailwind-css-55f81b65f9e4

*Fonte complementar:* https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/in-defense-of-utility-first-css-4f406acee6fb/?utm_source=sharklabs.com.br&utm_medium=post-vue-tailwind-utility-first&utm_campaign=vue-tailwind-utility-first

Comment: Certo, vou fazer. Obrigado pelo comentário.